# How to implement the code which redirect clients request to another node

Tags: sockets, redirect, forward

I'm very curious about how to implement redirect code in a back server node.
For example: Client A request web server C, there is a load balance node B between A and C. So the graph is `A=>B=>C=>A (not A=>B=>C=>B=>A)`. Actually C get requests from B, so I'm wondering how does C create a socket to connect to A and send data to A. I highly appreciate if you would share me some code snippet about this, Thanks!

Comment: This is rather vague. Are you making web requests? Web requests can be redirected with HTTP codes, meaning that A will be able to directly contact C using a specific URL. TCP doesn't allow native redirect, so you will have to do something above that if you are using raw TCP.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the question you are asking:

*"I have multiple web servers behind a load balancer, so how can I create a persistent http socket connection to a back end server from a client without it being redirected to another server and therefore breaking connection?"*

The answer to that question is through cookie injection. For example, with HAProxy you can set a cookie depending on the server that the request is routed to first, then the load balancer will know to stick that request in future to the specified server.

An example in HAProxy backend configuration:

```
backend socket-servers  
    timeout server  120s
    balance leastconn

    # based on cookie set in header
    # haproxy will add the cookies for us
    cookie SRVNAME insert
    server node-1 127.0.0.1:5000 cookie S1 check
    server node-2 127.0.0.1:5001 cookie S2 check
```

This example was taken from http://toon.io/configuring-haproxy-multiple-engine-io-servers/.

Upon a new request it will see no cookie, and route to the best server based on the server with the least number of connections. As it does so, it sets a cookie SRVNAME=node-1 or SRVNAME=node-2 depending on the server it goes to. Every subsequent request from the client goes to the node specified in the cookie.